# <video> in <a href="#">

Tags: html

How do I put a < video > in `<li><a href="#"><p>Ethnics</p></a></li>`

Using the video as below:

```
<video width="320" height="270" controls>
<source src="steve_powell_320_hard.mp4"  type="video/mp4; codecs=avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2">
<source src="steve_powell_320_hard.webm" type="video/webm; codecs=vp8, vorbis">
<source src="steve_powell_320_hard.ogv"  type="video/ogg; codecs=theora, vorbis">
</video>
```

UPDATE for Šime Vidas
HTML

```
<ul class="lists_video" id="list">
        <li><a href="#" class="video_trigger">Ethnics</a><video width="320" height="270" controls>
                    <source src="video/steve_powell_320_hard.mp4"  type="video/mp4; codecs=avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2">
                    <source src="video/steve_powell_320_hard.webm" type="video/webm; codecs=vp8, vorbis">
                    <source src="video/steve_powell_320_hard.ogv"  type="video/ogg; codecs=theora, vorbis"></video></li>
        </ul>
```

CSS and JS as suggested by Šime Vidas with sample codes.

Comment: Paste the code inside? What's the problem?

Comment: A video as a link per se and it should open with width="320" height="270". It is not viewable until opened, that is the idea of <li>.

Comment: Sorry it is an oversight...got two <a href="#">. It is removed.

Comment: @Irishgirl I don't follow. Do you want the video to be hidden initially, and then be displayed when the anchor is clicked?

Comment: Yes thats it...I want the video to be hidden initially, and then be displayed when the anchor is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
<ul id="list">
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="video_trigger">Ethnics</a>
        <video width="320" height="270" controls>
            <!-- your <source> elems here -->
        </video>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#list video { display: none; }
```

JavaScript:

```
$( '#list' ).on( 'click', '.video_trigger', function () {
    $( this ).siblings( 'video' ).show();
});
```

So, you hide the VIDEO element(s) initially with CSS. Then, when a `.video_trigger` anchor is clicked, its corresponding VIDEO element is displayed.

Comment: It almost work on both firefox and Safari. It plays automatically without me clicking a link with a sound background but can't see a video?

Comment: I've updated the HTML as above.  I can hear the sound but can't see a video using your code.

Comment: @Irishgirl Afaik, VIDEO elements don't auto-play by default. I'm not sure what triggers the video playback. *** When you click on the anchor, does the video show up?

Comment: @Irishgirl I would have to see your complete code. Put it on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) if you can.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/jaNynZ0E  I did not include CSS and you can use this for CSS. #list video { display: none; }

Comment: @Irishgirl You have to put your jQuery code in a ready handler: `$(function () { /* code here */ });`. Btw, JavaScript code belongs at the bottom of the page, not in the head.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Ok I'll try this. DO you mean <script src="js/1.8.2_jquery.mobile.js"></script><script src="js/1.8.2_jquery.min.js"></script> as bottom of a page or your JS e.g. $(function ()

Comment: @Irishgirl All the SCRIPT elements that are in your page head should be at the bottom of the page, below the content, and right before `</body>`.

Answer (score 1):

This works perfectly for me. Unless I'm missing something here?

```
<li>
    <a href="http://whatever.com">
        <video width="320" height="270" controls>
            <source src="steve_powell_320_hard.mp4"  type="video/mp4; codecs=avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2">
            <source src="steve_powell_320_hard.webm" type="video/webm; codecs=vp8, vorbis">
            <source src="steve_powell_320_hard.ogv"  type="video/ogg; codecs=theora, vorbis">
        </video>
    </a>
</li>
```

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SaHku/

Note how click on the video opens the url.

EDIT

I think this is what is really wanted:

```
<a href="#" onclick="$('#video').show(); $(this).hide();">Show Video!</a>
<div id="video">
    <video width="320" height="270" controls>
        <source src="steve_powell_320_hard.mp4"  type="video/mp4; codecs=avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2">
        <source src="steve_powell_320_hard.webm" type="video/webm; codecs=vp8, vorbis">
        <source src="steve_powell_320_hard.ogv"  type="video/ogg; codecs=theora, vorbis">
    </video>
</div>
<script>
$('#video').hide();
</script>
```

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fYFvQ/2/

This is assuming you have [jQuery](http://jquery.org)

Comment: Thank you. I'm hoping to put <video> inside <a href="#"> so you won't see a preview until opened, as I can see as above. Is it possible not to have a preview until opened?

Comment: oh right. okay then Could I recommend Javascript? Give me a sec to edit my answer

Comment: I've tried it and it plays automatically. I don't see any controls?

Comment: @NiallPaterson You can't lay out a string in multiple lines like that.

Comment: mp4, webm and ogv is for different browsers. So what is the best way of I can't use a string in multiple lines.

Comment: Yeah I figured that. you can either get rid of the new lines (I only put them in for clarity) or you can go with something like Sime's answer. The whole thing about siblings might be new to you if you haven't used jquery before but its cleaner

Comment: Updated Now. This now hides the link when its clicked aswell

Comment: This is updated video with a full URL source file and it does not perform the same the one you've an updated js fiddles with just a video name as source file. See http://jsfiddle.net/alma/AwZmh/1/